# Thread creation and starting

Tags: java

Is there a difference between

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
}

MyThread obj = new MyThread();
Thread t = new Thread(obj);
t.start()
```

Vs

```
obj.start()
```

Is there any advantage in choosing one over other?

Comment: Thread implements Runnable

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 5):

In general you should not extend `Thread`, but implement `Runnable` instead. Your example would then become:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

   public void run() {
      // Whatever needs to be done.
   }
}

MyRunnable obj = new MyRunnable();
Thread t = new Thread(obj);
t.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference: you should **not** extend `Thread`, but use `new Thread(myRunnable)`. This is similar to your first approach, only your way is misguided in extending Thread instead of implementing Runnable. So do this:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   public void run() { ... }
}

Thread t = new MyThread(new MyRunnable());
t.start();
```

or, more conveniently,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
  ... stuff ...
}}).start();
```

Be sure to distinguish the concepts of `Thread` and `Runnable`: the former is a heavy-weight handle to an actual system resource; the latter is just a holder of a method.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread t = new Thread(obj);` takes a `Runnable obj` - the recommended way.

`MyThread obj = new MyThread();` requires you to `extend` `Thread` which is **considered inadvisable** nowadays.

See ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/541487/823393) for details on the debate.

Answer (score 1):

Your object already extends Thread, so there's no need to wrap it in a new Thread object. If you were implementing Runnable instead, the first approach would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

`new Thread(obj)` delegates `Thread.run` to `obj`. This only uses `obj` as a `Runnable` and not as a `Thread`.

```
MyRunnable obj = new MyRunnable();
Thread t = new Thread(obj);
t.start();
```

Since (in your code) you are instantiating two threads (one that is started, and one that is never started, you pay some cost for the creation of an additional thread). Aside of this, the form with runnable leads to a better design, since you are not extending `Thread` for the only purpose of overriding `run`.

Had you implemented your logic with `Runnable`, you would be able to use [`ThreadFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html#newThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), and you would not longer be tied to the default implementation of `Thread` (which comes handy in some situations).

Answer (score 1):

This seems confusing at best.

I would rather implement the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, and then that object can be made available not only to a `Thread` constructor, but also to thread pools, executors etc. that consume `Runnable` objects for submission to threads at later times.